# Is there a way to change the height of a UINavigationBar in Storyboard without using a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to use a custom `UINavigationBar` in one of my views, which is not a part of any `UINavigationController`-hierarchy. When I drag a `UINavigationBar` into Storyboard, it shows like this:

[image: UINavigationBar]

This bar is 44px, which would be enough if the status bar wouldn't share this space. Because iOS7 lets us use the entire screen, including the space for the status bar, the `UINavigationBar` should be 64px tall, not 44px.

If I connect the view to a `UINavigationController`'s hierarchy, then it shows correct:

[image: UINavigationController]

I read somewhere that **if** the `UINavigationBar` has the property `barPosition:` set to `UIBarPositionTopAttached`, then the bar would be 64px. This is, however, a `readonly`-property.

My search results have only shown something I consider a "work-around". By adding a useless `UINavigationController` before this `UIViewController`, I can pretend to have a hierarchy, and it will add the `UINavigationBar` with 64px automatically.

Is there **really** no way to have a 'rogue'(without the help of a navigation controller) `UINavigationBar` that covers 64px?
If that is the case, is there any valid reasons as to why?

(I'm not saying the `UINavigationBar` should be 64px by default, but there should be an option for it in the inspector)

(I also see people answering with programmatic ways to solve this. Even though these answers works, I'd still have to *design* the storyboard with that in mind (a gap). What I want to know is if it's possible to set this in storyboard, or rather, why isn't it allowed?)

Comment: How do you change the height when using a UINavigationController? I have a UINavigatioController but the bar appears 44px

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can set the property `barPosition` to `UIBarPositionTopAttached` another way!

1. Add a delegate to your UINavigationBar.
2. Implement `-positionForBar:` in the delegate class:

   ```
   - (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
   {
       return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
   }
   ```

Your navigation bar's top must also be anchored to the Top Layout Guide.

Comment: You cannot set navigation bar's delegate while it owned by navigation controller

Comment: It's working and I think it's the most elegant solution. The question was how to extend a UINavigationBar below the status bar when it is NOT in a UINavigationController.

Comment: As trite as "this is by far the best option" comments are, this is by far the best option.

Comment: Ah yes, if I use constraints to lock the navigationBar to the topLayoutGuide (20px down) then this seems to work perfectly, thanks! Still wishing for support for making it work (visually) through Storyboard though, but I guess Apple won't let us do that..

Comment: How do achieve this in Swift?  You say set the delegate for the UINavigationBar, which is UINavigationBarDelegate, but the method you refer to is one from the UIBarPositioningDelegate protocol.

Comment: @DogNibbler The UINavigationBarDelegate protocol inherits from the UIBarPositioningDelegate protocol.

Comment: I've done a blog post walking through the steps of how to set this up: [Easily use a Navigation Bar without a corresponding Navigation Controller](http://user3526.blogspot.com/2016/03/easily-use-navigation-bar-without.html)

Comment: @leanne The link is down, I would really like to see how this is done. Do you possibly have it somewhere else?

Comment: @Objectif: the link is fixed.

Comment: @Objectif: the steps are also in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36212823/1107226)

Comment: Bonus - this works fine even with the iPhone X. Got rid of my previous hacks and used this instead. :)

Answer (score 26):

You can change the nav bar height programmatically:

```
[navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
```

Edit: As I wrote in the comments, you may have to put this line in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to circumvent autolayout.

Comment: Indeed I can, I actually never tried that, thank you. However, the height property in Storyboard is grayed out, so I assume there is a reason why we can't have 64px `UINavigationBar`'s **in Storyboard**, and I'd like to know what that reason is.. If I change the height programmatically, I'd still have to design the Controller in Storyboard with 'false' information, be it with a gap of 20px below the navBar, or with constraints while having 20px gap on the bottom of the view etc. My question is rather pointed at the limited function in Storyboard.

Comment: I tried this in both viewDidLoad and didFinishLauchingWithOptions. The height of nav bar did change but it was set again to default. Am I getting your idea wrong or there's something else I may miss?

Comment: @jchnxu try putting it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: I found this works in a `viewDidAppear:` method. BUT... the view below it wasn't updated to match the changed height. A nice enhancement to the answer would show how you adjust the other views (would it be the `UINavigationTransitionView` that shows up in the hierarchy?) to sync up with the change in size (in my case, I was trying to make it narrower, not bigger).

Comment: This works for swift:`override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
        navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, 64)
    }`

Comment: @Tristan.Liu what is "navbar"?

Comment: @Gargo It did in 2014, but probably doesn't anymore

Answer (score 10):

You can set it to attach to the top of the view using 'User Defined Runtime Attributes' in 'Identity Inspector' in Interface Builder. Set the `barPosition` property.

[image]

Here's the documentation for the `barPosition` property: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarPositioning_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I tested this is Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3 and it works perfectly! Nice!

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to accomplish this WITHOUT using a `UINavigationController` or setting it programmatically. Just set a height constraint on the navigation bar to whatever you want, 64 in this instance.

You can accomplish the same thing programmatically as such:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:navigationBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:64.0f]];
```

EDIT:

As @nerdist-colony pointed out, when working with Autolayout it's always been to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` otherwise there may be conflicts in the constraints.

Comment: I really like this idea. But when I employ it, I get a conflict resolution error:    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008d430 V:[UINavigationBar:0x13f53ad30(13)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17828eba0 h=-&- v=--& V:[UINavigationBar:0x13f53ad30(44)]>" How do you get rid of the `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`?

Comment: set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` to false

Comment: Tried that. Things didn't turn out so well. If I did it on the `self.navigationController.view`, a lot of stuff was just missing. And if I did it on the `self.navigationController.navitionBar`, I got an exception and died.

Comment: doesn't work for me too

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a standalone UINavigationBar too and I encountered the same issue, and I found there is two ways fixing this properly.

I fixed it using constraints, and a parent UIView. I set this UIView in the storyboard as the parent view of my UINavigationBar with a {0, 0, 320, 64} frame. You can add a constraint or a set of constraints forcing the UINavigationBar to have the desired size.
And given that your parent UIView has the correct frame in your storyboard, you can layout as usual your other views in your storyboard.

Now if autolayout is disabled you can change the bar height programmatically as described in Lindsey's answer.
`-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` seems to be a good spot to do it.

Comment: Do you mean adding ANOTHER UIView (subview of the main view) to nestle the UINavigationBar into? And, can you elaborate on how to set the constraints?

Comment: @leanne KKetch's solution works for me in Xcode 7.2. You describes it right: Just add an another UIView to the main view and add the UINavigationBar as a child of the new UIView.

Than set constraints relative to the Superview of the UIView as follows: Leading Space = 0, Trailing Space = 0, Top Space = 0, Height = 64.

The UINavigationBar constraints relative to the Superview (Your new UIView) are: Trailing Space = 0, Leading Space = 0, Bottom Space = 0, Top Space = 0

Answer (score 2):

If you using Autolayout, you can set Height of UINavigationBar's constraint to 64 or event more.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post detailing how to do this with minimal code intervention. Your bar will show a gap in the storyboard, but it will work fine on the device. In short, the steps are:

1) Add the navigation bar to the view controller in the storyboard.

2) Set the constraints for the navigation bar in the storyboard:
   - Navigation Bar.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom
   - Navigation Bar.Leading = Superview.Leading
   - Navigation Bar.Trailing = Superview.Trailing

3) Connect the storyboard's navigation bar to its view controller as an @IBOutlet.

4) In the view controller's class, add a UINavigationBarDelegate protocol to the class declaration.

5) In the view controller's viewDidLoad method, set the navigation bar's delegate to self.

6) In the view controller, add the bar positioning delegate's positionForBar method. Return the UIBarPosition representing TopAttached. (Note: UINavigationBarDelegate inherits this method from UIBarPositioningDelegate.)

The full post with GIF images is here:
[Easily use a Navigation Bar without a corresponding Navigation Controller](http://user3526.blogspot.com/2016/03/easily-use-navigation-bar-without.html)

These steps work as of Swift 2.1/Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 using the main storyboard you can use constraints to change the height and make it work.  This was the way that I found is easy to implement.

[Creating the constraints.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdIw1.png)

[What it looks like in the end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJHVA.png)

Answer (score 0):

@startupThekid:

iOS will generate an exception if you try to change autoresizing mask for a UINavigationBar that is managed by a UINavigationController.

However, the Swift equivalent of the objective C code you posted is:

```
var navBar = self.navigationController!.navigationBar
```

in **viewDidAppear**():

```
navBar.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

*Wherever you need to set the constraint:*

```
var navBarHeightConstraint = 
      NSLayoutConstraint(item: navBar, attribute: .Height,
            relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, 
            attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: height)

self.view.addConstraint(navBarHeightConstraint)
```

*Therafter you should be able to modify the constant property of the constraint as necessary to alter the nav bar height, such as for change in device orientation*

Comment: you are right! downvoting without comment is a no-go from my point of view. +1 from me for that.

Comment: It should be `navBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

Comment: Ah, yes @MarkusRautopuro, I fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `;` in Swift :) (It seems I can edit these also - removed it)

Comment: Thanks, I work in multiple languages for my day job, just habit. I haven't coded in Swift for several months :-)

Comment: This still causes the app to throw an uncaught exception: `'Cannot choose layout method for UINavigationBar managed by a controller'`. That's my reasoning for a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat and having problems, but now I've fixed it. I'm trying to do the right things to avoid setting the frame explicitly, which is desirable for future-proofing and easy support for different device sizes. In my case, I'm wanting a webview beneath a navigation bar.

I'm setting my view controller to be a `UINavigationBarDelegate` and implementing `positionForBar:` to return `UIBarPositionTopAttached`, like [user3269713's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21548900/592739). It seemed like the other trick was to use auto-layout to position the bar below the topLayoutGuide.

This *was* the code I was using in `viewDidLoad` after creating navigation bar & webview programmatically, and I was still seeing the bar stuck at height 44 but couldn't immediately see why:

```
    [navigationBar sizeToFit];
    navigationBar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    id guide = self.topLayoutGuide;
    NSDictionary *viewNamesDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView, navigationBar, guide);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[webView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewNamesDict]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[guide][navigationBar][webView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewNamesDict]];
```

But I did some more thinking and playing around with auto-layout, and it turns out it that alone was the cause of my problem. I was trying to rely on navigation bar's translated constraints from its autoresizing mask, but it turned out I needed to defined them explicitly. Here's my new `viewDidLoad` code that works:

```
    [navigationBar sizeToFit];
    navigationBar.delegate = self;
    navigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    id guide = self.topLayoutGuide;
    NSDictionary *viewNamesDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView, navigationBar, guide);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[navigationBar]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewNamesDict]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[webView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewNamesDict]];
    NSString *verticalLayoutVisualExpression = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[guide][navigationBar(%f)][webView]|", navigationBar.frame.size.height];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalLayoutVisualExpression options:0 metrics:nil views:viewNamesDict]];
```

And yes, as I'd hoped, this automatically moves the bar when turning to landscape and the status bar hides.

(I heartily recommend a auto-layout helper like Masonry which makes layout code more concise, and Masonry, for one, takes care of turning off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for you)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very hacky way of doing this, but for me it worked. I have a `NavigationViewController` and I want to load a ViewController modally which has a `UINavigationBar` at the top with Done and Cancel buttons. This is what it looked like:[image]

As you can see there is a white band at the top that I want to be the same color as the `UINavigationBar`. Instead of changing the height of the `UINavigationBar` programmatically, I just made a new view and set its background color equal to that of the `UINavigationBar` (HEX = F8F8F8, RGBA = 248,248,248,1.0). Again, I know this is super hacky, but it gets the job done for me. Here is what it looks like now

[image]

Comment: I have a post here asking how to do this (without hacking) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031707/uikit-navigation-bar-fill-height-to-top-of-screen