# Setting status bar hidden is messing with my navigation bar background image size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

In my app I want to change only one view controller status bat to hidden.

So in the view did load method I added this:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Thats what allot of the guides online said to do.

Now, this view controller is a table view, and I have set its nav bar background image to something custom, it looks like this before Im hiding the status bar:

[image]

And after I added the hidden method:

[image: enter code here]

So you can see it cuts part of the bg image (with the green line).

my nav bar bg image size is `640 × 128` and I put it on X2 in xcode, so this should cover the whole nav bar after hiding the status bar.....isn't it?

please help,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The status bar is 20 pixel in hight so either you need to programmatically increase the size on the UINavigation controller hight just for that view controller of you need a smaller background image for that view controller.

Comment: how do i do it programatically ?

Comment: it depends on how you setup your views. Take a look at this there are several ways of doing what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439167/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-height-of-a-uinavigationbar-in-storyboard-without-u