# Carousel in controller is messing with sizes in my collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, collectionview

I have a UICollectionView on the top of my view and also a ListView, when I click on one item of the ListView it opens a new controller with two (hidden/unhidden) bars at the top and bottom and a WebView in fullscreen with Carousel.
I use tap or swipe normally but after I close my new View (I have a X in the top bar) it shows the previous view but suddenly the Collection size is smaller in height. ¿How do I prevent this?

I've been looking around and it is the same problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716164/setting-status-bar-hidden-is-messing-with-my-navigation-bar-background-image-siz) but the difference that my problem is NOT the NavigationBar, is the Collection beneath the NavigationBar.

I've been hours with this and I need someone to point me in some direction.

**EDIT**
[image]

[image]

[image]

***EDIT - UPDATE***

I have in my first view the ListView one, a

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: showFooMode....`

I do have an observer in another view, it is the common view for my whole app because it have the menu in the left and it changes the data in the right:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showfooMode:) name:@"showFooMode" object:nil];
```

And the selector method....

```
-(void)showfooMode:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"Show fooView in the GeneralView);
        FooItem *foo = [notification.object objectForKey:@"foo"];
        NSInteger currentIndex = [[notification.object objectForKey:@"foo"] integerValue];

        auxFooView = [notification.object objectForKey:@"delegate"];
      //  currentIndex = 20;

        fooView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fooView"];
        [fooView setNews:news];
        [fooView setDelegate:self];
        [fooView setCurrentIndex:currentIndex];
        fooView.view.alpha = 0;



        [self.view addSubview: magazineVC.view];
        [self addChildViewController:fooView];


        fooView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        NSDictionary *views = @{@"childview": fooView.view};
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-0-[childview]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[childview]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            fooView.view.alpha = 1;
        }];
```

Comment: Can you please add some screenshots or sketch?

Comment: I''ve made some sketch so you can see them. Hope this help to my explanation

Comment: Is your 2nd controller hiding the status bar?

Comment: Yes, indeed is hiding it

Comment: I think the reason that you have a constraints to the top of the view instead to the top layout guide. If is not that try showing the statusbar again in viewWillDissapear of your 2nd VC.

Comment: You need to tell us about the constraints and how these views / controllers are added and removed

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain how this is made: (see Edit in question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I achieve it, and now this is not happening any more. This will work only if you don't need the navigation bar, and can set your own custom bar. 
The way I do this is NOT creating the top bar programmatically  I create it in the layout and after that everything was working correctly. I asume that the main problem was in the 2nd View because it was a full-screen mode.