# iOS navigation bar changing height landscape vs portrait

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way to prevent the default UINavigationController in an iOS app from changing height automatically when the device is rotated from portrait to landscape?

In the screenshots below, the navigation bar is changing height by 10 or 15 pixels, which is causing the right-justified uiview (black bar) to extend outside the bounds of the navigation bar in landscape mode.

I want the navigation bar to keep a constant height.

**Portrait**

[image: Portrait]

**Landscape**

[image: Landscape]

Comment: I also facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it, if you use `UINavigationBar` which is in `UINavigationController`.

Another solution - hide standard navigation bar and show your custom in each UIViewController.
After that you can use solution from this posts:

[Is there a way to change the height of a UINavigationBar in Storyboard without using a UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439167/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-height-of-a-uinavigationbar-in-storyboard-without-u)

Comment: that's the idea i was considering but wasn't sure if it was necessary.  now i know.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change the top view's constraint in the view controller.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
if (_topConstraintForHandlingNavBarHeight) {
    _topConstraintForHandlingNavBarHeight.constant =  self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}
}
```

And this works fine for all views.