# different navigationbar Height in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

How to create topbar like in right controller (it has width more than in left navcontroller)?

[image]

i've tried to create any controllers with same properties, but width of bar in left navcontroller and right are same.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do like select your `Viewcontroller` --> select `navigationBar` --> go to attribute Inspector on `NavigationItem` --> select `Prompt`--> add **one/More  space in your keyboard** on their field , it increase size on your TopBar/NavigationBar Height

for example

[image]

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the way to change the `navigationbar`(which is draged by yourself) height is to add `constraints`.

Comment: @aircraft - no need of constarinst

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `nav bar height` programmatically:

```
[navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 84)];
```

Edit: As I wrote in the comments, you may have to put this line in viewDidLayoutSubviews to circumvent autolayout.

[Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439167/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-height-of-a-uinavigationbar-in-storyboard-without-u)