# embedded UINavigationViewController sets navigationBar height incorrectly, but corrects itself

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am embedding a UINavigationViewController into a parent view controller as follows:

```
-(void)presentChildController:(UINavigationViewController *)childController {
  UIView *formView = childController.view;
  formView.alpha = 0.0;
  [self.view addSubview:formView];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    currentController.view.alpha = 0.0;
    formView.alpha = 1.0;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [currentController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [currentController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [currentController removeFromParentViewController];
  }];
  [self addChildViewController:childController];
  [childController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
  currentController = childController;
}
```

As you can see below, the navigationBar height is incorrect.

[image: Invalid NavigationBar Height]

Clicking on one of register or Recover, replaces the UINavigationViewController with another one. And this second controller gets the navigationBar correct. Switching back, the first one fixes itself too. It's only wrong the first time. I have tried `[childController setNeedsStatusBarUpdate]` but that has no effect.

[image: NavigationBar height fixes itself]

The childControllers are all created the same way.
I am out of ideas as to what to try next. Any thoughts? Any additional information needed?

[UPDATE]: The navigation bar seems to be the right height. However, it contains something called an _UINavigationBarBackground (as seen in the view heirarchy), that's set to the wrong height. Any change to that appears to be disallowed as the navigationBar is controlled by the UINavigationViewController. 
[UPDATE]: Even a simple rotation causes the UI to correct itself.

Comment: I wonder if you have gone through this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439167/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-height-of-a-uinavigationbar-in-storyboard-without-u

Comment: Tried that. However, the navigationBar delegate cannot be set when it is managed by a UINavigationController. Results in:

    Cannot manually set the delegate on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller

Comment: Note, I don't use the storyboard, as I am controlling all this programmatically.