# Error creating a UINavigationBar in custom UINavigationController class

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a custom UINavigationController which I access from my storyboard and I want to customize the height of the nav bar by creating a custom nav bar. Here is what I have so far:

```
var navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main().bounds.width, height: 70.0))
navBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 155.0/255.0, green: 155.0/255.0, blue: 155.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
super.init(navigationBarClass: navBar, toolbarClass: nil)
```

In the last line I am getting this error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UINavigationBar' to expected argument type 'AnyClass?'
```

Anyone know why? Could it be a bug.
I am using Xcode 8 beta and Swift 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super.init(navigationBarClass:` expects a class (`AnyClass`) as parameter.
You have an object `navBar` which is object (not class) of `UINavigationBar` class and you are trying to set object to class parameter. Use next for correct initialising:

```
super.init(navigationBarClass: UINavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
```

For bar height you could try to use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20440989/2739795